# Cannot fetch the value from JsonArray

Tags: php, json

I am having problem fetching out the value from PHP coding to my android. The logcat shows that

> :W/System.err: org.json.JSONException:

No value for posts.

This is my php code:

```
<?php

require("config1.php");

$query="SELECT commentName,comment FROM discussion_comment WHERE discussID = :discussID";
        $query_params=array(':discussID'=> $_POST['discussID']);

try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();

if ($rows){
    $response["success"]=1;
    $response["message"]="Post Available";
    $response["posts"]= array();

    foreach ($rows as $row){
        $post = array();

        $post["commentName"] = $row["commentName"];
        $post["comment"] = $row["comment"];

        array_push($response["posts"], $post);
        }

        echo json_encode($response);

        }else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No post Available!";
        die(json_encode($response));

?>
```

When is remove the `'WHERE discussID = :discussID"'`, I am able to fetch the data, but some is not necessary. What other way to write with Where condition.
My java:

```
private static final String COMMENT_NAME="commentName";
    private static final String COMMENT="comment";
    private static final String COMMENT_VIEW_URL="http://fysystem.com/show_comment.php";

@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            try {
                json=jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(COMMENT_VIEW_URL);
                JSONArray jsonArray=json.getJSONArray("posts");
                for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
                    json=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    commentName=json.getString(COMMENT_NAME);
                    comment=json.getString(COMMENT);
                }
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: `JSONException: No value for posts`. Definitely you have no results using some discussID values, that cause error.

Comment: What is the correct way to write? I need to compare the discussID from database to that it only fetch the needed data.

Comment: Simply check if key exists in JSONObject before fetching it.

Comment: Is that anything wrong with my php coding, that is what I am asking.

Comment: No, problem in Android side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PHP**

```
<?php
require("config1.php");

// Default message
$response = array('success'=>0, 'message'=>'Error. Pass required parameters');

// Check discussID exists in POST params
if(isset($_POST['discussID']) && $_POST['discussID']!=""){
    $sql = 'SELECT `commentName`, `comment` FROM `discussion_comment` WHERE `discussID` = :discussID';
    try {
        // Hope $db is defined in config1.php
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
        $stmt->execute(array(':discussID'=> $_POST['discussID']));

        $response = array("success"=>0, "message"=>"Discussion Not found");
        // If data exists
        if($stmt->rowCount()>0){
            // Fetching rows with a scrollable cursor
            // http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php
            $posts = array();       
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $posts[] = array('commentName'=>$row['commentName'], 'comment' => $row['comment']);
            }

            // Set the success status 1 and add the posts in return response
            $response = array('success'=>1, 'message'=>'Discussion found', 'posts'=>$posts);
        }
        $stmt = null;
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
       // print $e->getMessage();
       $response = array('success'=>0, 'message'=>'DB Error');
    }
}

// Finally return the response
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

**Andorid**

```
try {
    json=jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(COMMENT_VIEW_URL);

    int success = json.getInt('success');
    // Check before access posts data
    if(success==1){
        JSONArray jsonArray=json.getJSONArray("posts");
        for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
            json=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            commentName=json.getString(COMMENT_NAME);
            comment=json.getString(COMMENT);
        }
    }else{
        // Handle it here if parameters not exist or db error or no discussion found
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but it still not able to fetch :(

Comment: share the log of return response

Comment: D/attempt: {"success":0,"message":"Error. Pass required parameters"}

Comment: It means that discussionID is not passed to the backend. I hope `json=jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(COMMENT_VIEW_URL);` you are passing the post parameter called discussionID

Comment: For testing you can try GET method by passing discussionID directly from URL

Try this, In Android, 
`json=jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(COMMENT_VIEW_URL + "?discussionID=<specifiy the discussionID>");`

In PHP change `$_POST` to `$_GET`